# Getting Facebook credentials

Tags: android, facebook

I got "Login with facebook" option in my app, which needs to get userid, firstname, lastname, email, profile pic, sex from his facebook account(if logged in) and send it to the server. I searched for it for a while but could not understand the solutions. how can i achieve this? link to some examples would be great

Comment: the person who down voted, at least give me the link to the similar question

Answer (score 0):

May be these links will help you

[Android-Hackbook](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/guides/mobile/android_hackbook/)

[Friends list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5789882/i-want-to-list-of-facebook-friend)

Comment: it says i need to have a facebook app. i have an app "built for websites", can i use it or should i have a separate app for mobile- "built for mobile"